# Best Practices for storing passwords in Windows Azure

Tags: passwords, azure

For those in the know, what recommendations do you have for storing passwords in Windows Azure configuration file (which is accessed via RoleManager)? It's important that:

1) Developers should be able to connect to all production databases while testing on their own local box, which means using the same configuration file,

2) Being Developers need the same configuration file (or very similar) as what is deployed, passwords should not be legible.

I understand that even if passwords in the configuration were not legible Developers can still debug/watch to grab the connection strings, and while this is not desirable it is at least acceptable. What is not acceptable is people being able to read these files and grab connection strings (or other locations that require passwords).

Best recommendations?

Thanks,

Aaron

Answer (score 1):

Hum, devs are not supposed to have access to production databases in the first place. That's inherently non-secure, no matter if it's on Azure or somewhere else. Performing live debugging against a production database is a risky business, as a simple mistake is likely to trash your whole production. Instead I would suggest to duplicate the production data (eventually as an overnight process), and let the devs work against a non-prod copy.

Comment: I understand, but the core issue is where/how these passwords should be stored in the first place. Developers for instance connect to a "dev" environment, which should also be secured.

Comment: Passwords and the like (connection strings) should be stored in your azure package configuration file. That's the logical place for that. Then concerning the "dev" environment, I think there are 2 simple practices 1) know the persons that you trust with credentials 2) change credentials when people quit the dev team.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be solved partially by a kind of credentials storage service.
I mean a kind of service that do not need a passwords, but allows access only for machines and SSPI-authenticated users which are white-listed.
This service can be a simple WebAPI hosted under SSLed server, with simple principles like so:
0) secured pieces have a kind of ACL with IP whitelist, or machine name-based, or certificate-based whitelist per named resource, or mixed.
1) all changes to stored data are made only via RDP access or SSH to the server hosting the service.
2) the secured pieces of information are accessed only via SSL and this API is read-only.
3) client must pre-confirm own permissons and obtain a temporary token with a call to api like 
https://s.product.com/
3) client must provide a certificate and machine identity must match with the logical whitelist data for resource on each call. 
4) requesting of data looks like so:
Url: https://s.product.com/resource-name
Header: X-Ticket: value obtained at step 3, until it expire,
Certificate: same certificate as it used for step 3.

So, instead of username and password, it is possible it store alias for such secured resource in connection string, and in code this alias is replaced by real username-password, obtained from step 4, in a Sql connection factory. Alias can be specified as username in special format like obscured@s.product.com/product1/dev/resource-name

Dev and prod instances can have different credentials aliases, like product1.dev/resource1 and product1/staging/resource1 and so on.

So, only by debugging prod server, sniffing its traffic, or by embedding a logging - emailing code at compilation time it is possible to know production credentials for actual secured resource.